# Confusion over facebook JS SDK login

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have two seperate js files, **domready.js** and **fb-jssdk.js**.

The jssdk handles loading the sdk and login. It returns the correct state from response.state when the user is logged in or not depending on the scenario.

What I am confused about is how I can use that obtained data from FB response and with the FB.api to get name and email when a user is logged in and use it on my site with jQuery.

**Edit:**
I want to know how to use the content of response in a separate js file from the one that the fb code is in and use it with jQuery event handlers.

So if I have a function called testAPI() which prints response.name to the console, how do I get the data of response.name = "Kryptonite Dove" to work with in the other file?

**testAPI()**

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    var state = response.name;
    return response.name;

});
}
```

**some func**

```
   $("#id").click(function() {
      if (response.name == "Kryptonite Dove") {
        // Do something
      }
   });
```

Comment: I have said that it is returning the correct state with response.state and have followed the documentation on the facebook dev site to test this. But that is not my question, so in terms of reading things more...

Comment: @KyrptoniteDove - Oh well I commented on this question before you edited it with more code and thought.

Comment: @RPM Wrong again I'm afraid. You did comment before I edited but not before I had said "It returns the correct state from response.state when the user is logged in or not depending on the scenario." Check the version history if you need more proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to access `response`, which is a local variable in a different function (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). So one thing you could do is assign that to a global variable, and then access it in your other function.

```
var saved_response;

function testAPI() {
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      var state = response.name;
      saved_response = response;

      return response.name;
  });
}



$("#id").click(function() {
   if (saved_response.name == "Kryptonite Dove") {
     // Do something
   }
});
```

Comment: I've been looking at this page, I'm not that comfortable with javascript to be honest and I'm struggling to understand how that helps me.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes you made in your question. Hope that helps

Comment: Yes that worked thanks, I'd tried to store response.name but must have changed it back to a local var in the func. Thankyou!